# Does ability damage from the "Pressure Points" Ninja Trick stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The Ninja Trick "Pressure Points" states:

> **[Pressure Points](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/ninja#TOC-Ninja-Tricks)** (Su): A ninja with this trick can strike at an
>   opponent’s vital pressure points, causing weakness and intense pain.
>   Whenever the ninja deals sneak attack damage, she also deals 1 point
>   of Strength or Dexterity damage, decided by the ninja. Unlike normal
>   ability damage, this damage can be healed by a DC 15 Heal check. Each
>   successful check heals 1 point of damage caused by this trick. A ninja
>   with this trick receives a +10 insight bonus on this Heal check.

Based on the wording, it seems that the ability damage would stack, however that seems entirely too powerful to me. Is there a clear ruling that states whether or not this is a stacking, or non-stacking, damage?

Comment: In our experience this ability is more of a minor debuff than anything overpowered.  It'd take ~10 rounds before it became a significant issue for typical enemies, and typical enemies don't last that long anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course it stacks.  Damage always stacks. Note under Bleeding Attack it clarifies that the bleed doesn't stack with itself - no such wording in Pressure Points.  And "Each check heals 1 point of damage..." pretty much cinches it (if you couldn't take multiple points of damage, that wouldn't be necessary to say). A DC 15 Heal check to remove the damage is a pretty easy mitigation. And the ninja is the one outstanding case where the Paizo folks chucked balance out the window, so yes, all the abilities are pretty good.